# Adding Google map layer in Openlayers - what about this function?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps

How to add Google map as a layer (something like  "*var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Streets*", {visibility: false})"?) to this *mymap.js* function i already have:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: 'map',
//  allOverlays: true,
    theme: null,
    projection: sphericalMercatorProj,
    displayProjection: geographicProj,
    units: 'm',
    numZoomLevels: 18,
    maxResolution: 156543.0339,
    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(
        -20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34
    ),
    controls: [
        new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher()
        
    ],
    layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM('OpenStreetMap', null),
        sundialsLayer,
        sprintersLayer,
        poisLayer
    ],
    center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0),
    zoom: 2
});
```

---

Note: suggested answer is fine -

```
    layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM('OpenStreetMap', null),
        new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        "Google Streets", // the default
        {numZoomLevels: 20},
        )
        
        sundialsLayer,
        sprintersLayer,
        poisLayer
    ],
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the layers array, just add the following:

```
new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                "Google Streets", // the default
                {numZoomLevels: 20}
            )
```

In addition, you need to make sure that you refer to the Google Maps Library, by using the following tag:

```
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
```