# Adding a google Maps Layer to OpenLayers 2.14

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps

I have a well-working map consisting of several layers in OpenLayers retrieved from geoserver. Now, I want to add a Layer from google maps. 
Since I did not find any working explaination in the web - how do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean one of the Google maps base layers? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59223/adding-google-map-layer-in-openlayers-what-about-this-function

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I tried and failed doing so (TypeError: google.maps is undefined)

Comment: Did you also load the JS file from google: 
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script> If you did, please post some code.